# Set executable permission from Windows host on Linux filesystem

Tags: python

I have a python script which runs on a Windows machine. On this machine I have mounted a Samba filesystem (on a Linux host).

When I now try to change file permissions on the filesystem with `os.chmod(S_IXUSR)` it doesn't set the excutable permission, since it is hardcoded in Windows to not do anything as some research I did suggests.

Do I have any chance to change unix file permissions from a Windows host using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Slightly longer answer: It would perhaps not be impossible to write a Windows Samba driver which supports this, but you seem to be asking for an existing solution.